# Same Intent Service running multiple background tasks parallely (ISSUE)

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

```
public class DataManager extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public DataManager() {
        super("DataManager");
        setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        // download and parsing task done here
    }
}
```

This is my intent service which i am using to download file and parse it. Now if i get a new request for a file download, i have to clear the ongoing task and start the download for new request cancelling the older one. so i use the below code for doing it :.

```
private void refreshSync() {
    context.stopService(new Intent(context, DataManager.class));
    final Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, DataManager.class);
    mServiceIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

So the service gets killed and the next request to start service is intented. But the previous tasks starts again running two parallel tasks performing download. Basically the previous task doesnt get killed which i intended to.

Is there any work around to kill the ongoing task of the service and start another fresh task ?

Comment: As far as I know (and it stated in the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html ) only one task can be performed at a time. So it might be a mistake within the onHandleIntent implementation. Could you elaborate on how you loading files?

Comment: I download multiple files from s3 through retrofit call and then it is stored in database one by one

Comment: Are the retrofit calls synchronous? Otherwise the service is not in charge of their progress. You also want to cancel request via retrofit itself. BTW How do you understand that two tasks execute in parallel?

Comment: Yeah the retofit was running in another thread, which service isnt parent of. As service isnt a process who spawned that thread. so killing service doesnt help. I had to kill the retrofit service running in a different thread. That solved the problem. Thanks Aleksandr Madvedev

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `IntentService`. This doesn't match your requirements. `IntentService` is a simple `Service` that accepts a queue of work and processes the queue and then shuts itself down when the queue is empty.

You need more intelligence, and you are better off implementing that yourself. Just `extend Service` instead of `IntentService`. In `onStartCommand()` start a background `Thread` that downloads the data. Keep track of that background `Thread` in a member variable in the `Service`. If `startService()` gets called again, check if you already have a download in progress. If so, stop it and start a new background `Thread` to download the new file. To stop a background thread, you should provide a `boolean` variable in the `Thread` that gets examined every now and then inside the download loop. If that variable's state changes, it means the `Thread` should stop. This is a standard mechanism for stopping background threads in Java.

Comment: Yeah it is solved before.. thanks for the input and the solution

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `setIntentRedelivery(true);`, that force the intents to survive calls of the service if they are not handled completely (if `onHandleIntent` doesn't manage to return). Taking into account the fact that IntentService has only one working thread (can execute only one task at a time) the behavior of the service completely depends on the `onHandleIntent` implementation. So you need either analyze implementation and change it according to you goals, or set `setIntentRedelivery(false);`

Comment: I have tried that too. But the progress intent shows up again as soon as i start the next intent resulting two process at a time